# Qiucksort Ligado, ¿cómo ordeno por dos criterios?

Tags: c++, lista, ordenamiento, quicksort

Intento hacer un ordenamiento por dos criterios (primero frecuencia y despues codigo ASCII) para una practica en la universidad, me dijeron que habia que agregar una condicion más pero no se me ocurre nada, espero me puedan ayudar. Ejemplo:

```
10 A
10 C
10 X
12 B
12 R
```

Anexo el quicksort ligado que tengo.

```
void TDA_Huffman::ordenarLista(NodoAL* leftEdge, NodoAL* rightEdge) {
if(leftEdge == rightEdge) {
    return;
    }

NodoAL *i(leftEdge), *j(rightEdge);

while(i != j) {
    while(i != j and i->getFrecuencia() >= rightEdge->getFrecuencia()) {
        i = i->getNext();
        }

    while(i != j and j->getFrecuencia() <= rightEdge->getFrecuencia()) {
        j = j->getPrev();
        }

    if(i != j) {
        cambiar(i, j);
        }
    }
if(i != rightEdge) {
    cambiar(i, rightEdge);
    }
if(i != leftEdge) {
    quickSort(leftEdge, i->getPrev());
    }
if(i != rightEdge) {
    quickSort(i->getNext(), rightEdge);
    }
}
```

Comment: podrias agregar un ejemplo de cual es tu salida en este momento?

Comment: ahora mismo solo ordena por un criterio: 10, 12, 15, 18

Answer (score 0):

Para ordenar por dos criterios debes comparar en base al primer criterio y si el primer criterio tiene valores equivalentes entonces comparar por el segundo criterio; tú no lo estás haciendo, tus únicas comparaciones son sobre la frecuencia por lo que es normal que sólo te ordene en base a dicho criterio:

```
while(i != j and i->getFrecuencia() >= rightEdge->getFrecuencia()) {
//                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- ¿Y el otro criterio?
    i = i->getNext();
    }

while(i != j and j->getFrecuencia() <= rightEdge->getFrecuencia()) {
//                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- ¿Y el otro criterio?
    j = j->getPrev();
    }
```

La implementación podría parecerse a:

```
bool compara_nodos(const NodoAL& l, const NodoAL& r) {
    return (l.getFrecuencia() < r.getFrecuencia()) ||
           ((l.getFrecuencia() == r.getFrecuencia()) && (l.getASCII() < r.getASCII()));
}
```

La función anterior devuelve `true` si `l` debe ser considerado previo a `r`.

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sjRDGgWnk3kiFIym)</kbd>.